# TryGetEntity Usage with respect to composite keys

Tags: wcf-data-services

How do you use the tryGetEntity method when you have composite keys?

Can it be done, if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method takes the URL pointing to the entity, not key properties. Now most of OData servers use a convention to address entities by using key properties in the URL. That convention is described here http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#AddressingEntries. But I would strongly suggest against trying to compose that URL yourself (it's easy to get it wrong).
Maybe if you posted what is the scenario you want to get working, a better answer could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm trying to do is cache some of the entities locally. E.G. assume Customers have States (and states have multiple keys). I would like to cache the states on the client (isolated storage) so when I pull down a customer and I expand the customers State I now have a context with 2 entities a customer and a state.

In the UI I might want a list of States in a combo box that the user can choose from, but I don't want to pull down the states every time since states never change. So I need to go through and find if the state is in the context before I add the state to the list of states to the context. This is were I do a TryGetEntity. I've been able to do this succesfully with entities with multiple primary keys (constructing the URL by hand using name value pairs) but it is awkward at best.

First off it seems that you can not use key value pairs in the url if there is only one key, only if there is more then one.
Secondly it seems that the order of keys makes a difference?

I agree with you composing the URL manually is problematic - that is why I asked the question.

Obviously, my example is a simplification of the real situation, but you should be able to see where I'm going with this.

Comment: Instead of using TryGetEntity to find whether a particular state is already present in the context, you can try using Context.Entities.Where(e => e.Entity.GetType() == typeof(State) && ((State)e.Entity).ID == keyValue); You can write these query for multiple keys also - you get the idea. If the number of entities in the context is not huge, the performance of this won't be bad.

Comment: Or you can store the Identity of the entity when you serialize it to the isolated storage. Call GetEntityDescriptor with the instance and on the returned object access the Identity property and store that. Later on you can use that as the parameter to the TryGetEntity.